# Use JQuery to select table elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following table:

```
<table id="selected_data_sources">

<tbody>
  <tr id="sel_item_PCAAT00"><td>PCAAT00</td></tr>
  <tr id="sel_item_PCABN00"><td>PCABN00</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

How can I get the IDs (PCAAT00 and PCABN00) in the  pairs using JQuery? Thanks!

Comment: what do you want in jquery?

Comment: In the pairs? What do you mean?

Comment: you want id like this PCAAT00 and PCABN00 ?

Comment: << in the pairs >> What does it mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question is somewhat unclear, but this will return the text contents of every `<td>` in the table, if that's what you're after:

```
var ids = $('#selected_data_sources tbody td').map(function() {
    return $(this).text();
}).get();
```

The `.get()` on the end is only required if you require a real array (with all of its associated methods available) rather than an *array like object*.

Comment: Maybe $(this).text() ?

Comment: thanks! i wished i can upvote you, but couldn't due to my low reputation.

Answer (score 2):

try this code `.each` is faster than `.map`

check this out http://jsperf.com/test-each-vs-map

```
var x='';
$('#selected_data_sources tbody td').each(function() {
    x+=$(this).text()+' ';
});
alert(x);
```

Comment: why do you think that `.each` is faster than `.map` ?  The only difference is that `.map` accumulates the results of the callback in an array instead of throwing them away.  If the desired result is an array then `.map` is _exactly_ the right function to use.

Comment: proof -> http://jsperf.com/test-each-vs-map `.map` creates a new array  which make it slow and lower performance.

Comment: ok, one clarification - there's probably some overhead in the way that `.map` constructs a new jQuery object on its object stack out of the array.

Comment: I wouldn't consider that a significant difference.  If you want an array, you _should_ use `.map`.

Comment: yes if we want result as an array it's fine but still `.each` is faster

Answer (score 0):

you can use javascript as :

```
var tabel = document.getElementById('selected_data_sources');

for (i = 1; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
            var currentRow = table.rows[i];

        }
```